# Cannot build the sciter-rs example, -lsciter-osx-64 not found

Tags: macos, rust

I downloaded the sciter SDK, extracted it, and added it to my `PATH` (`PATH = $PATH:DOWNLOAD_PATH/bin.osx`). I then tried to run the example:

```
$ cargo run --example minimal

Compiling sciter-rs v0.4.1 (file:///Users/username/rust/rust-sciter)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
|
= note: "cc" "-m64" "-L" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/username/rust/rust-sciter/target/debug/deps/sciter.0.o" "-o" "/Users/username/rust/rust-sciter/target/debug/deps/libsciter.dylib" "/Users/username/rust/rust-sciter/target/debug/deps/sciter.metadata.o" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/Users/username/rust/rust-sciter/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "-l" "sciter-osx-64" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/liblazy_static-7f1b96a3a3eb529d.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libobjc_foundation-01845fbb083d910e.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libblock-498e22772f250b8c.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libobjc_id-1b90e6745bca1976.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libobjc-9578ff0dad145ffa.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libmalloc_buf-7aa64dffd2b03b4f.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/liblibc-ad32fde1bd850538.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libstd-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libpanic_unwind-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libunwind-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/librand-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libcollections-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/librustc_unicode-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/liballoc-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/liballoc_system-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/liblibc-a4729905.rlib" "-Wl,-force_load,/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libcore-a4729905.rlib" "/var/folders/sk/76ww7m4n1j5210m9vxc88hy40000gn/T/rustc.SOetAnbslBvu/libcompiler_builtins-a4729905.rlib" "-framework" "Foundation" "-l" "System" "-l" "objc" "-l" "objc" "-l" "objc" "-l" "System" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-dynamiclib" "-Wl,-dylib"
= note: ld: library not found for -lsciter-osx-64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't understand why sciter-osx-64 library not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [rust-sciter](https://github.com/pravic/rust-sciter). The getting started instructions start with:

1. Download [Sciter SDK](http://sciter.com/download/) and extract it somewhere.
2. Add target platform binaries to `PATH` (`bin`, `bin.osx` or `bin.gtk`) and install Sciter shared library to your `LIBRARY_PATH`.
3. Build library and run the minimal sciter sample: cargo run --example minimal.

It looks like you didn't install the Sciter shared library (`sciter-osx-64.dylib`) to your [`LIBRARY_PATH`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html).